# Specifying the desired CPU for Fargate in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

my team is using Fargate to scale our service.

We'd like to use [Graviton](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/ec2-graviton/?trk=2d4b12f5-8693-4a5d-bc01-a61230b5c0d1&sc_channel=ps&s_kwcid=AL!4422!10!71743361021152!71743883859444&s_kwcid=AL!4422!10!71743361021152!71743883859444&ef_id=4134ea716e5210bdfb0a8986b33570ee:G:s) but I'm not sure how to specify specific CPU types. For example, if I think `T4g` is the instance that would manage the workload how can I do this?

So far the closest I've got to specify CPU instance in CDK is by specifying the the cpuArchitecture property in runtimePlatform to ARM64.

More broadly speaking, how does AWS decide which instance type to use? Obviously the instance has to be available in the region but I'm curious how AWS sets default values when not specified or what instance to use when it's only given an architecture.

Here's the Fargate task definition so far.

```
const taskdef = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, `mytask`, {
   taskRole: myRole,
   cpu: 512,
   memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
   runtimePlatform: {
        cpuArchitecture: CpuArchitecture.ARM64
   }
});
```

But obviously this doesn't give me much insight into which cpu instance will actually be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "instance types" in Fargate. The whole point of Fargate is that AWS manages the underlying EC2 instances for you, so that you don't even have to think about them. You have no visibility into what EC2 instances are running your Fargate containers.

With Fargate you simply [specify the CPU and RAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html#fargate-tasks-size) you want to reserve for your task, and Amazon finds a server with that amount of CPU and RAM available, and deploys your task to it.

You have already specified everything you can regarding the CPU requirements for your Fargate task. You have specified 512 for the CPU value, which reserves 0.5 CPU cores on the underlying server for your task, and you have specified that your container(s) were built to run on ARM architecture, so Amazon will deploy your task to a server with a Graviton CPU instead of an Intel CPU.